# How to compress this code further?

Tags: excel, vba

in the below code i am comparing values in 4 different columns with predefined values, and returning the value of the highest row in column named "size". is there a better way to write this code using arrays?

```
Sub CalculatetierJP()

Dim i, n, lth, wth, ht, wt, dwt, tier, flth, fwth, fht, fwt, ftier, dmwt As Integer

i = 2
n = 1
lth = 33
wth = 34
ht = 35
wt = 28
dwt = 36
tier = 37
GL = 17


Cells(1, 37) = "Size"
Cells(1, 50) = "Non-media/Media"
Cells(1, 51) = "Final tier"
Cells(1, 52) = "flth"
Cells(1, 53) = "fwth"
Cells(1, 54) = "fht"
Cells(1, 55) = "fwt"
Cells(1, 56) = "ftier"

' 1-Small
' 2- Standard
' 3- Oversize
' 4- Heavy Bulky

Do While Not Cells(i, n).Value = ""

If Cells(i, 7).Value = "y" Then

  'Set all to zero
   flth = 0
   fwth = 0
   fht = 0
   fwt = 0
   ftier = 0
'''**********************************
''Calcualte the tier based on length
'''**********************************

If Cells(i, lth) < 30.48 Then
    flth = 1

ElseIf Cells(i, lth) >= 30.48 And Cells(i, lth) < 50.48 And Cells(i, wt) < 12000 Then
    flth = 2

ElseIf Cells(i, lth) >= 30.48 And Cells(i, lth) < 50.48 And Cells(i, wt) >= 12000 Then
    flth = 3

End If

Cells(i, 52).Value = flth

'''**********************************
''Calcualte the tier based on width
'''**********************************
If Cells(i, wth) < 20.32 Then
    fwth = 1

ElseIf Cells(i, wth) >= 20.32 And Cells(i, wth) < 40.64 And Cells(i, wt) < 12000 Then
    fwth = 2

ElseIf Cells(i, wth) >= 20.32 And Cells(i, wth) < 40.64 And Cells(i, wt) >= 12000 Then
    fwth = 3

End If

Cells(i, 53).Value = fwth
'''**********************************
''Calcualte the tier based on height
'''**********************************
If Cells(i, ht) < 10.16 Then
    fht = 1

ElseIf Cells(i, ht) >= 10.16 And Cells(i, ht) < 25.4 And Cells(i, wt) < 12000 Then
    fht = 2

ElseIf Cells(i, ht) >= 10.16 And Cells(i, ht) < 25.4 And Cells(i, wt) >= 12000 Then
    fht = 3

Cells(i, 54).Value = fht

End If
'''**********************************
'''Calcualte the tier based on weight
'''**********************************

If Cells(i, wt) < 1000 Then
    fwt = 1

ElseIf Cells(i, wt) >= 1000 And Cells(i, wt) < 12000 Then
    fwt = 2

ElseIf Cells(i, wt) >= 12000 Then
    fwt = 3

End If

Cells(i, 55).Value = fwt

'''**********************************
'''Calcualte the final tier
'''ftier = Max(flth, fwth, fht)
'''**********************************

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("audit").Activate
'Set myrange = Worksheets("audit").Range("AV2:AX2")
ftier = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(flth, fwth, fht, fwt)
Cells(1, 56).Value = ftier

' 1-Small
' 2- Standard
' 3- Oversize
' 4- Heavy Bulky

If ftier = 1 Then
    Cells(i, 37) = "small"

ElseIf ftier = 2 Then
    Cells(i, 37) = "standard"

ElseIf ftier = 3 Then
    Cells(i, 37) = "oversize"

ElseIf ftier = 0 Then
    Cells(i, 37) = "Did not calculate"

End If

Cells(i, 39).Value = Cells(i, 47).Value

End If
Dim row1 As Integer

row1 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 2 To row1

i = i + 1

Next i

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Your first `Dim` statement isn't compressing code; it is declaring everything but the last (e.g. `dmwt` ) as an **[Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tyd4tfw8.aspx)**, not an integer. Sometimes the fastest and best code is written in longhand.

Comment: Quick note, except for `dmwt`, all your other variables are `Variant`.  Unfortunately, you can't list a bunch of new variables and set them all to the same type, as you tried.  You have to do that for each unique one.  (A quick tip, you can do `Dim ftier&` as a quick shorthand for `Dim ftier as Long`, `Dim ftier%`for `Integer`.)

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestions. I will try to implement them. For some reason the loop is not running through the entire range. it just running once.can you help me figure it out?

Comment: Do. Or do not. There is no try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with your code incrementing the `i` count variable at the end. The first issue is that you are incrementing twice: once on the `i=i+1` and once on `Next i`. the other issue is that in that for loop, you are just running though all of the used range. To fix this, you need to remove the for loop and just keep the `i=i+1`